# Can't find installed programs

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, vpn, search

I'm trying to install a VPN client (selected correct .DEB package etc)

I run using `sudo dpkg -i example.deb` and it goes through fine and it says it's installed.

Now when searching for the program (correct name) nothing ever comes up, this has happened with three VPN clients now.

I've also checked the dependencies and they're all installed and I've ran:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Tell us which clients you install so that I can try to install them too. Maybe they don't create a .desktop shortcut and you need to create one yourself. Or, look at `/usr/share/applications` and if the client you are looking for is there, then edit the `.desktop` entry and see if there is a line that says `NoDisplay=true` or `OnlyShownIn= SOME_DESKTOP` or `NotShownIn= SOMEDESKTOP`.

Answer (score 0):

VPN's are added to network manager. So see network manager at the top right

Comment: Already reloaded the network manager. My issue is that they're an actual client (like GUI)